# Setting up Elastic Search, Kibana, Fleet and Elastic Agent

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

When setting up Elastic Search, Kibana, Fleet Server and Elastic Agent using the docker compose file provided in the Elastic Search 8.8 documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html) we have to login to the GUI and modify the outputs settings Eg: modify the Elasticsearch URL add ssl.certificate_authorities in advanced YAML configuration. How can we preconfigure these values without logging into the GUI. Checking kibana.yaml file the updates made on GUI are not there so wondering where these values are stored?

Wondering if xpack.fleet.agents.fleet_server.hosts and xpack.fleet.agents.elasticsearch.hosts will solve this?

What xpack configuration is needed for the advanced yaml ssl configuration ?